# After upgrade to 16.04 the Desktop UI is broken

Tags: unity, 16.04

[image]

Here is a screenshot of some of the windows and how they look since I've upgrade to Ubuntu 16. It's the Ambiance theme, but the Radiance theme looks the same. The High Contrast there sort of works but it has other problems.

Things of note

- Background is black but it's set to be the default Ubuntu wallpaper
- Inputs (text, checkboxes, sliders, etc) ui missing borders and background
- Borders around windows and buttons are missing
- Hover states of various ui elements such as drop downs don't work
- There is no padding between list/tab items

Things I've tried

- rebooting
- updating && upgrading
- restarting unity
- tried changing gtk-window-decorator to compiz-decorator
- ensured ubuntu unity plugin was enabled
- tried changing themes
- re-installing ubuntu-desktop

System Specs:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64 bit)
- 16 gb ram
- i7-4790K @ 4 ghz
- Geforce GTX 970

Does anyone have any idea what's going on and how to solve this?

Comment: I gave up looking for solutions and reinstalled Ubuntu 16 from scratch.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Too bad you didn't fix it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue in the future, I had the exact same UI problem after trying out `gnome3-staging` ppa's `gnome-terminal`. Here's how I fixed it.

Try resetting `compiz` and `unity` configurations first (be sure to backup config files first!)

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
unity --reset
```

For me that didn't work. However, I remembered I added `gnome3-staging` ppa right before so removed it

```
sudo ppa-purge pa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
```

Removing `gnome3-staging` ppa fixed everything for me

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer because I recall playing around with the gnome-terminal staging when true colors were introduced.

Answer (score -1):

I experienced the same issue when I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 16.10. I solved it by changing the theme provided by Unity Tweak Tool from arc-dark which is what I was using to a paper theme. I also realized that the radiance theme equally solved the issue

Comment: OP is using 16.04 and they mention that Radiance didn't fix it for them... so I don't think it is the same problem